# Creating SEO friendly URLs with URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I need to make [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) friendly URLs with [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) from:

```
http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/index.php?service=example1&location=city1

http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/cars.php?service=example1&location=city1

http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/bicycle.php?service=example1&location=city1
```

to

```
http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/example1/example2/index.html

http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/example1/example2/cars.html

http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/example1/example2/bicycle.html
```

My URL rewriting doesn't work at all,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/(\w+)/?$ index.php?service=$1&location=$2
RewriteRule ^cars/(\w+)/?$ cars.php?service=$1&location=$2
RewriteRule ^bicycles/(\w+)/?$ bicycles.php?service=$1&location=$2
```

And where should I put the [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file? In the root or a subfolder?

Comment: Are you sure you dont want: http://www.myurl.com/subfolder/cars/example1/city1.html?

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /subfolder/$3.php?service=$1&location=$2 [L]
```

You should put it in the root directory.

Comment: How could I adjust this code for the following link:

http://thegrantmag.com/issues?which=feb